# Why does this string search and replace segfault?

Tags: c++, string, segmentation-fault

`colours` is a `std::map<string, string>` where the first element of each pair is a 2 letter `std::string` colour code, and the second element is the 7 character `std::string` shell escape code for that colour.

```
size_t i;
for(map<string, string>::iterator iter = colours.begin(); iter != colours.end(); iter++) {
    while((i = text.find(iter->first)) != string::npos) {
        text.replace(i, i + sizeof(iter->first), iter->second);
    }
}
```

When this code is run, the program segfaults. My best guess is that it is something to do with the length of the replacement string being longer than the length of the string it's replacing, but to the best of my knowledge that can only cause segfaults with `char *`, not `std::string`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`string::replace` takes a start position and a length, not a start position and an end position.  Also `sizeof` does not return the length of a string.  So the third line should probably read:

```
text.replace(i, iter->first.length(), iter->second);
```

For what it's worth, `sizeof` returns the amount of *stack* space consumed by the object, which is known at compile time.  So it cannot vary from call to call, which the string's length does.

Comment: Thanks, I have made the changes you have suggested, but the program still segfaults on this block of code.

Comment: @Not Joe Bloggs, hmm.  Run in a debugger, to find out exactly what conditions is causing it to segfault?

Comment: @Not Joe Bloggs Can you give an input that results in a segfault?

Comment: The map definition is [pasted here](http://stikked.com/view/22202099) and an example of a failing input is "{gtest{x"

Comment: Actually, found the problem. It was elsewhere in the same function as this code.

Answer (score 1):

@luqui already answered why it segfaults, but I wanted to add something else.

Be careful not to end up in an infinite loop in the case where you your replacement string contains the search string. You can avoid this by passing `string::find()` a position to start searching. This will also improve efficiency as your current solution could degenerate to O(N<sup>2</sup>).

Comment: In this case, the search and replace strings are known at compile time, so I can say the replace string definitely does not contain the search string.